# Tomcat in docker remote shutdown

Tags: tomcat, docker

In order to shutdown a Tomcat docker container gracefully, is it possible to issue a remote SHUTDOWN command? rather than setting up docker to catch the kill request, and shutting down gracefully.

Default server.xml:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this page:
http://www.techpaste.com/2012/01/server-xml-container-configurations-tomcat-7-explained/

There is an 'address' parameter:

> This attribute specifies the TCP/IP address on which this server
>   listens for the shutdown command. The default value is localhost,
>   which means that the server can be shut down from the same machine
>   where it is installed (i.e., remote shutdown is disabled).

Setting the address parameter to 0.0.0.0 will enable the container to listen on the hosts IP address.

Server.xml

```
<Server port="8005" address="0.0.0.0" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

Map the shutdown port (in this case 8005) to a host port.

You can change the shutdown parameter to a random string, or use appropriate firewall/security groups to manage securing the port.